# How to display local placeholder image if image url response is null in react native

Tags: react-native, placeholder

I'm trying to show an image for which the source Uri is received from the API call.
It is working totally fine if the Uri is a correct link in a string format. But if the Uri link is null or not a valid link I would like to show a placeholder image(`placeholder2`) that is available locally.

Code:

```
       <Image
          style={styles.postImage}
          source={{
            uri: imageUrl,
          }}
          defaultSource={require('../assets/images/placeholder1.png')}
        />
```

I know `defaultSource` is used to show a temporary image when the real image is being loaded

My problem is if the Uri is null from the response, I'm seeing this error

[image]

But if I change the code to this, I see blank image (gray color)

```
       <Image
          style={styles.postImage}
          source={{
            uri: imageUrl || 
            "require('../assets/images/placeholder2.png')",
          }}
        />
```

[image]

And upon adding `default source` to the above code I can see the `placeholder1` image instead of `placeholder2`

```
       <Image
          style={styles.postImage}
          source={{
            uri: imageUrl || 
            "require('../assets/images/placeholder2.png')",
          }}
          defaultSource = {require('../assets/images/placeholder1.png')}
        />
```

Can someone help me to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

**Update**:

Answer by @louieKim actually worked for me

```
 <Image source={imageUrl ? {uri: imageUrl} : require('../assets/images/placeholder2.png')} >
```

Comment: uri: imageUrl ? imageUrl : require('../assets/images/placeholder2.png')

Comment: @louiekim When i add this then i see this error `JSON Value 10 of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString`

Comment: Hi, sorry was wrong about my first comment, Try this one <Image

source={imageUrl ? {uri: imageUrl} : require('../assets/images/placeholder2.png')}

>

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const url = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png';
const placeholder = require('./assets/snack-icon.png');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageSource: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImageSource(url);
  }

  getImageSource = url => {
    if (url) {
      this.setState({ imageSource: { uri: url } });
    } else {
      this.setState({ imageSource: placeholder });
    }
  };

  onErrorImage = () => {
    this.setState({ imageSource: placeholder });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image
            source={this.state.imageSource}
            style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
            onError={this.onErrorImage}
          /> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If i am correct, upvote pls.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply follow the old-school approach here:

```
 {imageURl!=null && <Image
          style={styles.postImage}
          source={{
            uri: imageUrl 
          }}
        />}

{imageURl==null && <Image
          style={styles.postImage}
          source={{
            uri: '../assets/images/placeholder2.png'
          }}
        />}
```

Comment: This approach is an inefficient way

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Image
  style={styles.postImage}
  source={{uri: your_image_url !== null ? 
    your_image_url : '../xxx/your_local_image'}}
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Image
    source={item.image ? { uri: item.image } : Images.no_image}
    style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', borderRadius: 20, }}
/>
```